# How do I set the record name myself when recording on CloudKit?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I can change the record name on the website. I couldn't find a way with the code.

```swift
let cloudsave = CKRecord(recordType: "iEmotion")
let recordName = CKRecord.ID(recordName: "1")
privateDatabase.save(cloudsave) { (savedRecord, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print("SUCCESSFUL") }
    else {"ERROR"}
}
```

I don't want it saved as a UUID.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
let recordName = CKRecord.ID(recordName: "1")
let cloudsave = CKRecord(recordType: "iEmotion", recordID: recordName)
privateDatabase.save(cloudsave) { (savedRecord, error) in
if error == nil {
    print("SUCCESSFUL") }
else {"ERROR"}
}
```

Comment: The code worked when I removed this line. Thank you for the answer. cloudsave.recordID = recordName

Comment: It is also not very helpful to edit the initial question. Now nobody who stumbles upon this will know what the problem was or what you wanted to achieve